# Syntax error during running my Python code

Tags: syntax-error, python

Just started learning Python as beginner and I found it fun. But it gave me strange errors mentioned below. I'm learning from a book and the code there is written as:

```
fish="basss"

if fish=="bass":
    print('super')
    else:
        print('bla')
```

It gave me a syntax error and I couldn't understood the reason. I have written my code as same as written in book. I've searched in google, but couldn't find anything. I'm using the latest version of python and I typed this in Python shell.

Answer (score 3):

Python is sensitive to indentation. Your code should be indented like this:

```
fish="basss"

if fish=="bass":
    print('super')
else:
    print('bla')
```

Answer (score 1):

because your `else` block isn't aligned with your `if` block, try un-indenting the `else`.

```
fish = "basss"

if fish == "bass":
    print('super')
else:
    print('bla')
```

Answer (score 1):

Python differentiates between code blocks by indentation. It is very important to have correct indentation in your code.

```
if fish=="bass":
    print('super')
else:
    print('bla')
```

`if` and `else` have to be at the same level of indentation. All statements to be executed within each of those conditionals have to be indented again.

Answer (score 1):

There is an indentation error , you have to do like this,

```
fish="basss"

if fish=="bass":
    print('super')    
else:
    print('bla')
```

Always else block should be under the same indentation level of `if` or `elif` statements.

Comment: If you are that much eager to learn python just take look at 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm and http://docs.python.org/2/library/ .

Answer (score 0):

You have to type it on multiple lines. The `if` and `else` statements cannot be on the same line. This causes an error, and so they must be typed in separate lines.